# How can I fix this generic type?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MergeSort{

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(LinkedList<T> outputSequence,
        LinkedList<T> leftSequence, LinkedList<T> rightSequence) {
        int i = 0; // Index into the left input sequence.
        int j = 0; // Index into the right input sequence.
        int k = 0; // Index into the output sequence.
        // While there is data in both input sequences
        while (i < leftSequence.size() && j < rightSequence.size()) {
            // Find the smaller and
            // insert it into the output sequence.
            T a = leftSequence.get(i);
            T b = rightSequence.get(j);
            if (a.compareTo(b) < 0) {
                outputSequence.set(k+1, leftSequence.get(i+1));
            } else {
                outputSequence.set(k+1, leftSequence.get(j+1));
            }
        }
        // assert: one of the sequences has more items to copy.
        // Copy remaining input from left sequence into the output.
        while (i < leftSequence.size()) {
            outputSequence.set(k+1, leftSequence.get(i+1));
        }
        // Copy remaining input from right sequence into output.
        while (j < rightSequence.size()) {
            outputSequence.set(k+1, leftSequence.get(j+1));
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(LinkedList<T> list) {
        // A list with one element is sorted already.
        if (list.size()> 1) {
            // Split list into halves.
            int halfSize = list.size() / 2;
            //LinkedList<T> rightlist =  new Comparable[list.length - halfSize];
            // Sort the halves.
            LinkedList<T> leftlist = (LinkedList<T>) (list.subList(0,halfSize));
            LinkedList<T> rightlist = (LinkedList<T>) (list.subList(halfSize, list.size()-1));
            sort(leftlist);
            sort(rightlist);
            // Merge the halves.
            merge(list, leftlist, rightlist);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 982,842,731,654,549,439,384,264,152,46 }; 
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i) {
            list.add(arr[i]);
        }
        MergeSort.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

In this code I am trying to sort using a linked list implementation. I have to use generic types because it could be String or Integer etc. But I have the error message in main `MergeSort.sort(list)` line. It says:

> The method sort(LinkedList<T>) in the type MergeSort is not applicable
>   for the arguments (LinkedList<Integer>)

How can I fix this?

Comment: as a tip convert the linked list at the start of sort to an `ArrayList` or an array, because otherwise the `get(idx)` calls will ruin the runtime. They will have the runtime `O(n)`.

Comment: I get a different exception when running your code: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.SubList cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedList`.

Comment: the methode `sublist` returns an instance of type `List<E>` and not `LinkedList<E>` so change the types of `LinkedList` to just `List`

Comment: @Ackdari My point is see the run time and expected time for linked list sorting. So I have to use Linked List. Also I didn't get the solution still. What do I have to write in main sort() method ?

Comment: @Ackdari "as a tip" or just use `Iterator`s.

Comment: Your code [compiles fine](https://ideone.com/svujvL#stdin). It's broken at runtime (in a number of ways), but the issue you describe here cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
 LinkedList<T> leftlist = (LinkedList<T>) (list.subList(0, halfSize));
 LinkedList<T> rightlist = (LinkedList<T>) (list.subList(halfSize, list.size() -1));
```

to

```
  LinkedList<T> leftlist = new LinkedList<>(list.subList(0, halfSize));
  LinkedList<T> rightlist = new LinkedList<>(list.subList(halfSize, list.size() - 1));
```

Comment: I fixed but I still have error in main sort(list) line.